# Do follower spouses still make money on their shop if they are out with you?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was considering getting Alea the huntress and use her to come out on adventures, but if the shop will close if she comes with me, do I need to find a better spouse?

Answer (score 4):

Yes she will make money even if she is out with you.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I can tell, anyone you marry will setup a store.<sup>[1](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage#NPCs_available_to_be_married)</sup>   I haven't married Alea specifically, so I can't confirm that she does, but I believe she *will* make money while out with you.

Comment: I can confirm she does.

Comment: Yes she does get a shop.

Comment: but does the shop generate income when she's not home?

Comment: This does not address the question.  Sure, the follower-spouse will open a store.  But the asker wants to know if that store will continue to earn income if your follower-spouse is absent from it.

Comment: @DavidB **yes**.